# How to update UITextField after deprecation of drawText(in:) in iOS 15

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, ios15

I have a subclass of UITextField that does some work to layout a 2FA input with a background for each charecter. Before iOS 15 I used drawText(in:) to layout the background of each character. Apple deprecated this as of iOS 15. How can I get this behaviour back?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619587-drawtext

Comment: You are asking: *"now that `drawText(in:)` is deprecated, how do I use [**this code**]"*? But... you haven't shown us ***this code***. We need to see what you're doing, and how you want the output to look, in order to offer any sort of help.